# Firebase - Edit other user data

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to edit email address and password for other user via code. Is this possible to do without Admin SDK? I'm asking because I dont have backend skills yet. Does Firebase have a method to login user via uid? Maybe this way I will made my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Users can only update their own data in mobile apps using the Auth client SDKs.  It would be a gigantic security hole if any user could modify or log in as any other user without credentials.

Comment: So I need to make my own custom authentication via backend? Do you have some guide how to implement node server on godaddy hosting? Also thanks for helping.

Comment: You need a secure backend. Look into Cloud Functions.